# Remember email on successful Laravel login checkbox

Tags: php, laravel

**login.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />

        <title>로그인 페이지</title>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>              
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#loginform').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault(); 

                    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');                    
                    var email = $('[name="email"]').val();
                    var password = $('[name="password"]').val();
                    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

                    var emailRegex = /^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
                    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
                        alert("올바른 이메일 형식이 아닙니다.");
                    }

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken
                        }
                    });
                    
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '{{ route('login') }}', 
                        method: 'POST',
                        data: {
                            email: email,
                            password: password
                        },
                        success: function(response, status, xhr) {
                    
                            if(response.success){
                                console.log(xhr.status);
                                alert('로그인 성공');
                                window.location.href = '/home';
                            }else if(response.fail){
                                alert('메일주소 또는 비밀번호가 올바르지 않습니다.');            
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            var errors = xhr.responseJSON;
                            console.log(errors);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>    
        <div class="container">
            <form id="loginform" action="/login" method="post">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <dl>
                    <dt>이메일</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" size="30" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                    </dd>
                    <dt>비밀번호</dt>
                    <dd>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size="30" require>
                    </dd>
                </dl>

                @isset($errors)
                    <p style="color:red">{{ $errors->first('message') }}</p>
                @endisset  

                <button type="submit" name="action">로그인</button>
                <br>
                
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                <label for="remember">이메일 기억하기</label>
                
            </form>
            <a href="/register">관리자 등록하기</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**LoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request)
    {

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        $remember = $request->filled('remember');

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)){

            $request->session()->regenerate();

            if ($request->filled('remember')) {
                $request->session()->flash('email', $request->input('email'));
            } else {
                $request->session()->forget('email');
            }

            return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['fail' => true]);
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'message' => '메일주소 또는 비밀번호가 올바르지 않습니다.',
        ]);
         
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laravel 메인 화면</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>안녕하세요!
        @if (Auth::check())
             {{ \Auth::user()->name }}님</p>
             <p><a href="/logout">로그아웃</a></p>
        @else
            게스트님</p>
            <p><a href="/login">로그인</a><br><a href="/register">회원등록</a></p>        
        @endif
</body>
</html>
```

Implementing remember email check on successful Laravel login. Authentication is performed in the login method of the LoginController.php file by passing the value to the server through ajax. I am not sure what code problem caused the error. I can't check remember my email. help

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax request only contains email and password values. You should also include your checkbox value in data that is being post to controller.

First step according to your code flow is to get value of a checkbox like.

```
let remember= $("input[type='checkbox']").val(); 

  $.ajax({
        url: '{{ route('login') }}', 
           method: 'POST',
           data: {
                   email: email,
                   password: password,
                   remember: remember
                 },
```

The problem was that you are not sending the value from your login.blade.php file. Give it a try and hopefully it will work.

Comment: I applied the code, but in chrome network I get "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'remember_token' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: update `admin` set `remember_token` = p0VUFqEwLwRBIdQoO0i90ea613Bb2ONzt4Yn4rpr5GryaPMmoMkCYR6FbCTB where `id` = 21)",

An error has occurred. can i know the cause??

Comment: @ChaeSeongLim check your admin table , based on this error means that you do not have remember_token column in your admin table